# Comprehensive Unix BIND DNS guide

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind

I'm running the latest version of CentOS on which I'm currently hosting Node.js projects with MongoDB and Lighttpd.

Everything is running very smooth but now I want to manage my own DNS on the machine because always contacting my ISP for domain changes is very annoying.

I'm pretty skilled and used to unix systems so I'm not starting without knowledge, I also have a very good understanding of how DNSes work, I just need a guide that'll show me how to setup BIND, and how to manage basic configurations with it.

Anyone knows a good guide for this?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Answer (score 6):

[O'Reilly's Cricket Book - DNS and Bind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100574)
[image: DNS and Bind]

The indispensable guide to setting up basic to intermediate BIND 9.x configurations.

There's also a newer edition which covers [BIND and IPv6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449305199); most of the new topics are pretty obvious to anyone who knows the content of the previous edition, and mostly irrelevant to what you're chasing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the CentOS/RHEL official deployment guide?

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-bind.html

It's for RHEL5, but RHEL6 is also using a bind 9.x, so your basic configuration shouldn't be significantly different.

Hmm, I see that wiki.centos.org doesn't have a HOWTO, so I guess the official 5.x docs is it.  I don't know why I can't find a 6.x equivalent.